# aix to xp with crossover, ping from xp works, ping from aix doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows-xp, aix

I'm in the process of removing a legacy system from the network and trying to connect an xp client machine directly to the AIX server, so as to still have access to the legacy application.

I connected the two machines with a crossover cable, gave the xp machine a fixed ip address, put the xp machine into /etc/hosts on the aix machine and put the aix machine into the windows hosts file. also renamed the resolv.conf file.

I can ping the aix machine from windows machine, and I can telnet into the aix machine or use winscp to view the aix file system from the xp machine, but pinging from the aix machine doesn't work, either by hostname or ipaddress.

Comment: Firewall on XP?

Comment: Why is it important that the AIX machine be able to ping the XP machine? Can the XP machine connect to the legacy application? Does the legacy application work? Also, why would you not have both machines connected to your switching infrastructure or to an isolated switch instead of using a crossover cable?

Comment: I did turn off the xp firewall, btw. The client appliation does NOT currently work, and that's why I'm pursuing the the ability to ping. Note that when I ping from the aix machine, the xp network connection status shows received bytes, but doesn't seem to respond.

No particularly good reason for using a crossover cable except I know we did it in the past for development purposes, and it was easier than chasing after another switch that i could isolate from the network.

Comment: found the problem, overlooked the newer better anti-virus that we didn't used to have. disabled that and everything works.